# GetAuthCookie() and change domain cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have one site: sales.mysite.com (ASP.NET MVC) and another site: configurator.mysite.com (Angular + ASP.NET Web API)

User login on sales.mysite.com and after that could go to configurator.mysite.com using reference. User have to ability to get access to configurator.mysite.com without login.

I used the following code in sales.mysite.com:

```
var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userId, remember);
cookie.Domain = ".mysite.com";
```

But I get auth cookie with domain:sales.mysite.com
Why ASP.NET ignores domain: ".mysite.com" and issues cookie for domain "sales.mysite.com"?

P.S. I get cookies for google domain: ".google.com"

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by adding  without any additional attributes for  inside